# Removing inverse duplicates in dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary containing some example keys and values:

```
{'a': ['b'],
 'c': ['d'],
 'x': ['y'],
 'y': ['x'],
 'i': ['j','k'],
 'j': ['i','k']
 'k': ['i','j']}
```

What letter the key is and which letters are values are irrelevant providing they are shown to have a relationship. I need to be able to remove any 'duplicate' key-value combination so that my dictionary would be displayed as follows.

```
{'a': ['b'],
 'c': ['d'],
 'x': ['y'],
'i': ['j','k']}
```

Comment: Can it be assumed there are no duplicates in the value? So `['b', 'b']` will never occur?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse that is correct, there will never be a key value duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn each entry to a `tuple` and use a `set` to get `O(n)` time.

```
d = {'a': ['b'],
 'c': ['d'],
 'x': ['y'],
 'y': ['x'],
 'i': ['j','k'],
 'j': ['i','k'],
 'k': ['i','j']}

seen = set()
to_remove = []
for key, val in d.items():
    entry = tuple(sorted(val.copy() + [key]))
    to_remove.append(key) if entry in seen else seen.add(entry)

for key in to_remove:
    del d[key]
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': ['b'], 'c': ['d'], 'x': ['y'], 'i': ['j', 'k']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution how you can have it in one single loop with a dict comprehension as a one liner:

```
{k: v for i, (k, v) in enumerate(d.items()) if not set(list(d.keys())[:i]).intersection(v)}
```

And if you want to have it really fast:

```
s = set()
dmod = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    s.add(k)
    if not s.intersection(v):
        dmod[k] = v
```

Both approaches assume your dict is named `d`.
Result:

```
# {'a': ['b'], 'c': ['d'], 'x': ['y'], 'i': ['j', 'k']}
```

However, I have to state here that your text description does not suit the expected example. It would be nice if you could update that.
Besides that: are you aware, that the algorithm you ask for is completely order dependent? No solution which returns the result you want will work reliably prior python 3.6 without explicitely using ordered dicts.
I don't know your use case, but is it ok that applying the same algorithm to a e.g. backwards ordered dict creates a different result?

Comment: This won't create the situation where only `'x':['y']` remains out of `'x':['y']` and `'y':['x']`. Same for the i, j, k set.

Comment: @MattEllen correct I simply was concentrated on the description `'duplicate' key-value combination` rather than the example, which differs from one another imo.

Comment: @MattEllen edited. Curious how fast the downvoters react on an edit - _if_ they'll ever come back or even remember this post

Comment: @SpghttCd I have removed my downvote and upvoted. Sorry, I was a culprit of being too quick to downvote :P

Answer (score 0):

Another one liner:

```
>>> d = {'a': ['b'], 'c': ['d'], 'x': ['y'], 'y': ['x'], 'i': ['j','k'], 'j': ['i','k'], 'k': ['i','j']}
>>> dict({tuple(sorted((k, *v))):(k, v) for k, v in d.items()}.values())
{'a': ['b'], 'c': ['d'], 'y': ['x'], 'k': ['i', 'j']}
```

The inner dict is built with the *sorted* tuples `(key, value1, value2, ...)` as keys and the `(key, [value1, value2, ...])` pairs as values. Obviously, for every sorted tuple, you keep the last `(key, [value])` pair (this matters only if the dict keys are ordered, Python >= 3.6). Then build a dict with these `(key, [value])` pair.

If you want to get only the first `key-value` (Python >= 3.6), just reverse the order of iteration of the original dict:

```
>>> dict({tuple(sorted((k, *v))):(k, v) for k, v in sorted(d.items(), reverse=True)}.values())
{'x': ['y'], 'i': ['j', 'k'], 'c': ['d'], 'a': ['b']}
```

If that's not clear, here's a more simple example. I want to keep the first list having a given length in a list:

```
>>> L = [[1], [2], [1,2], [2,3,4], [3], [5,2], [7,8,9]]
>>> {len(v): v for v in reversed(L)}
{3: [2, 3, 4], 2: [1, 2], 1: [1]}
```

We see that only the first value is kept:

```
[*[1]*, [2], *[1,2]*, *[2,3,4]*, [3], [5,2], [7,8,9]]
```

Because this first value is the last to be added to the dict and overwrite the next one (or previous one in reverse order).